# Changing Vim background color - and not text color

Tags: linux, vim, colors

I was hoping to see if I could change the background color of Vim, so that when I'm insert mode my background changes slightly. (my default is dark grey, i'm hoping to change to light grey).

I was following some other SO posts I found, and tried

```
autocmd InsertEnter * hi Normal ctermbg=darkgrey
autocmd InsertEnter * hi Normal ctermbg=none
```

That was slightly working, since it would change my background, but it also changed my text color too - I just want the background changed.

I tried adding in ctermfg (foreground?)

```
autocmd InsertEnter * hi Normal ctermfg=none ctermbg=darkgrey
autocmd InsertEnter * hi Normal ctermfg=none ctermbg=none
```

Still did not fix it.

Pictures for reference:

1. When I open up vi - Default colors - which I like - Command mode
   [image: When I open up vi - Default colors - which I like - Command mode]
2. When I go into "insert" mode (background subtly changes (good!) text changes (not what I wanted)
   [image]
3. Escaping out of insert, back to "Command" mode
   [image]

I google'd some more, and found another SO post, that was explaining how the way ctermbg works, is it doesn't just change the background color, instead use

```
set background=
```

I tried that too:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * set background=dark
autocmd InsertLeave * set background=light
```

It changes the font color and background color, but this time when I go back to command mode the font color is back to normal (along with the background).

Is it possible, to just change the background color between 2 color (light grey and  dark grey) without affecting text color, going from Insert Mode to Command Mode?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible, to just change the background color between 2 color
>   (light grey and dark grey) without affecting text color, going from
>   Insert Mode to Command Mode?

The answer is **yes**!

The trick consists in using GUI colors directly (like GVim) instead of terminal ones. Please try this:

1. Add `set termguicolors` before setting the colorscheme in your `.vimrc`
2. Add `autocmd InsertEnter * hi Normal guibg=#4D4D4D`
3. Add `autocmd InsertLeave * hi Normal guibg=#333333`

If your terminal is compatible and your Vim distribution is up-to-date, it should work.

*If you like dark Vim colorschemes, you might be interested in **Archery**. I have shared the project on GitHub: https://github.com/Badacadabra/vim-archery*